# Multiple timers behave erratically in .NET

Tags: c#, visual-studio, timer, windows-services

I am building an application that essentially runs a list of programs at specific intervals listed in a database.

There are 3 kinds of ways a program could be scheduled:

- at a frequency ie a set amount of times every day
- At a specific time every day
- at a frequency between a certain time, ie 4 times between 02:00-04:00

When running a single program with a single type of schedule my program runs perfectly and schedules at exactly the right moment.
But the problem seems to come in when I try and run more than one program and more than one type of schedule at a time.
The schedule becomes extremely erratic and opens the same program up multiple times, or runs a program that has been scheduled at a specific time in the past.
I have a function that calculates the exact milliseconds to the next event. In debug I have made this function log each time it does a calculation and for which program, and upon closely examining these logs, it works perfectly... which leads me to believe there could be something wrong with how I'm initializing the timers.

This is in my scheduled task class which runs the program and creates the next timer:

```
public void OnTimer(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs args)
    {
        taskSchedule.process = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(SystemFunctions.getFullExePath(taskSchedule));


        SystemFunctions.setLastTimeTaskRun(taskSchedule.id, DateTime.Now);
        taskSchedule.lastRun = DateTime.Now;

        System.Timers.Timer timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
        timer.Interval = SystemFunctions.determineNextTaskEvent(taskSchedule);
        timer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(this.OnTimer);
        timer.Start();
        taskSchedule.timerservice = timer;
    }
```

A new version of this class gets created each time for every program and every schedule of that program. So each timer and program runs independently.

This is how the Scheduled Tasks class are instantiated:

```
private void startScheduledTasks()
    {
        List<TaskSchedule> taskSchedule = SystemFunctions.getTaskSchedules();

        if (taskSchedule != null)
        {
            foreach (TaskSchedule currentTask in taskSchedule)
            {
                ScheduledTask scheduledTask = new ScheduledTask();
                scheduledTask.taskSchedule = currentTask;
                System.Timers.Timer timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
                timer.Interval = SystemFunctions.determineNextTaskEvent(currentTask);
                timer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(scheduledTask.OnTimer);
                timer.Start();
                currentTask.timerservice = timer;
                scheduledTasks.Add(scheduledTask);
            }
        }
    }
```

Like I said I have verified that the ms received from `SystemFunctions.determineNextTaskEvent(currentTask);` is accurate...

Does anyone know what could be causing this behaviour?

Comment: Do you ever `Stop` the timers?

Comment: I only ever stop the timers when the service ends... or when I need to modify the programs on the disk

Comment: I'm not too familiar with how Visual Studio treats timers, seems I'm treating them like Android Runnables... Do timers automatically restart in VS? I thought that once 'OnTimer' gets called it needs to be reinitialized?

Comment: I suspect you may find https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timers.timer.autoreset?view=netframework-4.7.2 of interest.

Comment: Lol yes that was very useful indeed xD Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are starting an excessive number of timers, and never stopping them.

I suspect you want to set [AutoReset](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timers.timer.autoreset?view=netframework-4.7.2) to `false`. *It defaults to `true`.*